# PHP: how to replace text, but only between certain identifiers?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

In PHP I need help with replacing certain content in a file that is between certain identifiers.

For example :

```
abcde
-BEGIN-
   bcdef
-END-
cdefg
-BEGIN-
   doo wah diddy
-END-
defgh
```

Let's assume I need to replace the 'd' character with a 'z', but ONLY *between* the `-BEGIN-` to`-END-` sections.  The result would then be :

```
abcde
-BEGIN-
   bczef
-END-
cdefg
-BEGIN-
   zoo wah zizzy
-END-
defgh
```

I tried `preg_match_all` to succesfully identify the -BEGIN- to -END- sections with:

```
$text = file_get_contents($file);
preg_match_all('#-BEGIN-.*?-END-#s', $text, $matches);
```

but can't figure out how to replace something inside these matches and return the whole text including the right replacements.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `preg_replace('/a([^(\-BEGIN\-|\-END\-)])/', 'z$1',$text)` ?

Answer (score 0):

[Preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) should do the trick.

Comment: How then?  I need a regex to identify the section and then replace the d only between each -BEGIN- and -END-

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback` for separating out the block, then use a second regex or string function within said callback to replace the searched letter.

Answer (score 0):

This searches the blocks inside **-BEGIN-** and **-END-** then replaces all occurences of the **d** character with **z** (hence the `preg_replace()` function in the 3rd line).

```
$str = preg_replace_callback(
    '~(?<=(?<=\n|^)-BEGIN-\n).*?(?=\n-END-)~s',
    create_function('$m','return preg_replace("~d~s","z",$m[0]);'),
    $str
);
```

**EDIT 1:** Changed the **m** flag to **s** in both Regex rules.

---

**EDIT 2:** If you want to make sure here's a better version of the Regex (all possible newline characters taken into account - Windows, Unix etc.).

```
    '~(?<=
        (?<=\n|\r|\r\n|^)   -BEGIN- \n |
        (?<=\n|\r|\r\n|^)   -BEGIN- \r |
        (?<=\n|\r|\r\n|^)   -BEGIN- \r\n
    )
    .*?
    (?=
        \n      -END-   (?=\n|\r|\r\n|$) |
        \r      -END-   (?=\n|\r|\r\n|$) |
        \r\n    -END-   (?=\n|\r|\r\n|$)
    )~xs',
```